# Deleting projects without refreshing the page will have an id undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my method where i try to delete a project (index comes from the ngFor in the template):

```
onDeleteProject(index: number) {
    console.log(this.projects[index].id) // always output the id
    this.projectService.deleteProject(this.projects[index].id).subscribe();
    this.projects.splice(index, 1);
}
```

This is how a project is added to the database:

```
public async myFunc(newProject: any): Promise<void> {
    const newProjectFromServer = await this.projectService.addProject(newProject).toPromise()

    await this.projectService
      .addEmployeesToProject(
        newProjectFromServer.id,
        newProject.assignedEmployees
       ).toPromise();

    console.log(newProjectFromServer.id); // always output the id
    this.afterSubmit();
}
```

So as you can see when i try to delete a project or submit a new project, they always have the id.
But if i try to delete a project that i just created, without refreshing the page or reinitializing the component, the id is actually undefined.
This is how i navigate from the new project form back to the projects list:

```
afterSubmit() {
    this.formSubmitted = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onFormAlertClose();
    }, 1500);
}

onFormAlertClose() {
    this.router.navigate(["projects"]);
}
```

Only if i refresh the page, the projects have the id and so the delete request get trough. So i get this error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/projects/undefined 500
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/undefined", ok: false, …}
error: {cause: {…}, message: "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to …berFormatException: For input string: "undefined""}
```

Edit: As requested, this is how i add the project once created. In the submit method:

```
this.projectService.addProjectToTable(newProject);
```

In the projectService this method is:

```
private addProjectToTable$: Subject<IProject> = new Subject<IProject>();

[...more code]

projectsTableChanged$ = this.addProjectToTable$.asObservable();

addProjectToTable(project: IProject) {
    this.addProjectToTable$.next(project);
}
```

And finally the project-list component where the table with the ngFor is, is updated like this:

```
addProjectAfterSubmit() {
   this.projectsTableChangedSubs =
       this.projectService.projectsTableChanged$.subscribe(
           (newProj) => {
               this.projects.push(newProj);
           }
       );
}
```

Comment: once the project is created, how do you add to *ngFor list ? It is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: ah yes, sorry i will edit the question.

Comment: How about sending the id to onDeleteProject instead of index ?

Comment: don't ever rely on the index because the index will always change on delete any item from the array

Comment: oh, i check a few times and it seemed to delete the right project. Any other way to tell to which project i pressed the delete button? (every project have one, it s also in the ngfor)